# PHP get method strangely working I don't know how solves

Tags: php, get, request

I need get method but not working

my code :

```
<?php
    $page = $_GET['page'] ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
    echo "current page : ".$page."<br/>";
?>
```

and

**$page's** result is 1. but i try `www.example.com/test.php?page=3`

**$page's** result is still output 1.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I tried this code with setting ?page=3, it outputs 3. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first you should check if is `page` setted, then you can access `page`

try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'] ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
    echo "current page : ".$page."<br/>";
}
```

here is the result i am getting:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You can just modify the statement,

```
$page = $_GET['page'] ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
```

to

```
$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$page = $_GET['page'] ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;
```

Is the short form for

```
if($_GET['page'] !== null){ $page = intval($_GET['page']); }else{ $page = 1; }
```

So there are at least two sources of error. "$_GET['page']" could be unset resulting in 1. If this was the case there would also be an error cause of the unknown variable.

It could be a string which is casted to 1 - in this case there is no error thrown.

For your needs it makes more sense to check for an existing variable like [mrustamzade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4459647/mrustamzade) proposed.

I would also check for a number like this

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page'])){
    $page = intval($_GET['page']);
}else{ $page = 1; }
echo "current page : ".$page."<br/>";
```